# Manipulating txt file from silverlight application ?

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, text-files, webclient

I'am trying to modify a txt file located on my server  ,for that i am using this code :

```
 WebClient webClientvent = new WebClient();
                webClientvent.OpenWriteCompleted += new OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(Readvent);
                webClientvent.OpenWriteAsync(new Uri("/v.txt", UriKind.Relative));

private void Readvent(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.Error != null) {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
            }
            WebClient webClient = (WebClient)sender;
            webClient.OpenWriteCompleted -= this.Readvent;
            Stream stream = e.Result;
            StreamReader monStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);


            try
            {


                StreamWriter monStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);


                monStreamWriter.WriteLine("first");
                monStreamWriter.WriteLine("second");


                monStreamWriter.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            } 

            }
```

But , Nothing is written in this Txt file ,am i missing something  ?

Answer (score 0):

handle [WebClient.UploadProgressChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) along with you need to upload the data also

```
webClientvent.UploadStringAsync();
```